# Activity with tabs work in debug but not working on release

Tags: android, layout, release

I'm using an activity with 3 tabs, this working perfectly in debug, but when I'm publishing the app and generate signed APK my application is crashing.

My layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The error message when is generated APK "application stopped"

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate (Unknown Source)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (Unknown Source)
  at com.app.sgi.AppMovil.ModuloCosecha.CensarCosecha.onCreate (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6294)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1108)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2369)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2476)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:150)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1344)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
        generatedDensities = []
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        return true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.4@aar'
}
```

Please help and thanks.
I can not understand why it works in development(debug) but it does not work in production (release generated APK)

Edited gradle (not working)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        generatedDensities = []
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        return true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }    
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        return true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.4@aar'
}
```

Comment: try removing this `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'`...and what is your `buildToolVersion`..?

Comment: My buildToolVersion android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

Comment: I'm trying removing "compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'" but not working

Comment: i am not sure if `27.0.2`..is a stable version yet...try downgrading `buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"`, and `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'`--Just a suggestion

Comment: Trying with 27.0.2 but not working

Comment: i am not asking you to try with 27.0.2..i am suggesting to downgrade the version to 26,0,1..

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm trying with 26.0.1 but no working

Comment: post the edited `build.gradle`..

Comment: Ready on post, see above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160964/discussion-between-rafsanahmad007-and-razodium).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find the error.
I try generate APK with ProGuard disabled in my build.gradle set minifyEnabled false like this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
```

I generate the APK and run perfectly with minifyEnabled false, but when minifyEnabled is true my app fail.

See this post:
[ProGuard with Android: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.util.Xml.asAttributeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474904/proguard-with-android-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-android-util-xml-asattribute)

My solution is set minifyEnabled true:

```
buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
```

And add one line to proguard-project.txt

```
-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *; }
```